# Получить список уникальных ключей, исходя из результатов запроса group by (MS-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Есть таблица с несколькими полями :

```
select unique_key, column1,column2,column3 from table1
```

Об этой таблице надо только знать тот факт, что поле unique_key - первичный ключ.
Задача - получить записи данной таблицы (ну или список unique_key), для которых совокупность полей (column1,column2,column3) продублирована минимум 1 раз (т.е. count(*)>1).
Как найти все возможные дубли и их количество - я могу с помощью запроса

```
select column1,column2,column3, count(*) as col_ from table1
group by column1,column2,column3
having count(*)>1
```

А вот как дальше сделать - не хватает навыков.

UPD. В любой из колонок (допустим) может стоять значение NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуемся [оконными функциями](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189461.aspx) и получим количества записей в нужном разрезе одновременно с данными, после чего во внешнем запросе отфильтруем требуемые записи. Это позволит выполнить работу за один проход и не потребует второй выборки из той же таблицы.

```
select *
  from (
   select unique_key,
          count(*) over(partition by column1,column2,column3) as cnt
     from table1
  ) A
 where cnt>1
```

Answer (score 1):

> А вот как дальше сделать

Если я верно понимаю написанное (в чём у меня большие сомнения), то

```
select unique_key, column1,column2,column3 
from table1, ( select column1,column2,column3
               from table1
               group by column1,column2,column3
               having count(*)>1
             ) as table2
where table1.column1 = table2.column1
  and table1.column2 = table2.column2
  and table1.column3 = table2.column3
```

**UPD:** Если некое поле может содержать NULL, все поля во всех сравнениях можно обернуть в COALESCE с заменой NULL на логически невозможное для конкретного поля значение. Либо просто SET ANSI_NULLS OFF.

Comment: Обновил вопрос - данная выборка не сработает, если при группировке в каком-либо поле будет NULL

Answer (score 1):

С учётом UPD я бы предложил сделать так:

```
SELECT a.unique_key
  FROM table1 a
 INNER JOIN (
              SELECT column1
                   , column2
                   , column3
                FROM table1
               GROUP BY column1
                   , column2
                   , column3
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1   
            ) b
    ON (a.column1 = b.column1 OR COALESCE(a.column1, b.column1) IS NULL)
   AND (a.column2 = b.column2 OR COALESCE(a.column2, b.column2) IS NULL)
   AND (a.column3 = b.column3 OR COALESCE(a.column3, b.column3) IS NULL)
```

Comment: `COUNT(*) AS cnt` в списке полей вывода в подзапросе не нужен.

Comment: @Akina согласен, можно убрать, но и, если оставить, не помешает.

Comment: Лишний расход памяти. Хорошо если групп десяток, а если миллионы? получить значение только для того, чтобы было? То есть я понимаю, что вряд ли сервер настолько умён, что по условию `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, найдя для группы вторую копию, сразу прервёт поиск-подсчёт остальных и перейдёт к обработке следующей, но всё же...

Comment: @Akina, замечание принял, запрос скорректировал.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, остался только маленький вопрос ради любопытства - я же могу заменить условие с COALESCE() на ISNULL()  (например, замена на пустоту или на 0, зная, что значения 0 в таблице быть не может). Насколько неправильным данный подход будет?

Comment: IsNull() и Coalesce() - это фактически одна и та же функция, только последняя имеет неограниченное количество аргументов.